# telegram bot php inline button keeps loading after answerCallbackQuery

Tags: php, telegram-bot

i have this code works fine
i get the callback data and i respond to the user with a Message
the thing is the inline button keeps showing the loading circle for a few seconds even after the response was sent to the user.
could this be a bug? or am i doing something wrong?

```
        elseif ($update && isset($update["callback_query"]))
    {

      //file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r($output , TRUE));
      $callback_query = isset($update['callback_query']) ? $update['callback_query'] : "";
      $chat_id = $update["callback_query"]['message']['chat']['id'];
      $data = $update["callback_query"]["data"];
      $callbackQueryID = $update["callback_query"]['id'];
      $this->answerCallbackQuery($callbackQueryID);

      switch($data){
        case 'someString':
        $this->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => 'string one was called'
        ]);
        break;
        case 'someString2':
        $this->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => 'stiring 2 was called '
        ]);
        break;
      }

    } // ======= END ELSEIF CALLBACKQUERY
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After searching in some forums and also in Telegram documentation I found the solution.
You have to use this function called [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery).
You have to call this method after the execution of the code associated with your button.

This is how I used this function

```
$webSite = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botToken;
function answerCallbackQuery($callbackId){
    $url = $GLOBALS['webSite']."/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=$callbackId";

    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

In this case, I only passed like params the callbackQueryId because I don't want to reply to the button but only remove the loading icon.

I hope this will help you and solve your problems